# Can you enable HTML5 elements in SilverStripe CMS

Tags: html, tinymce, silverstripe

I have a simple SilverStripe ( v3.1 ) page that is being managed in the CMS.

My goal is to dump some HTML into the content field using the html feature and have the page render the content as I need it.

The problem is the HTMLEditorField seems to strip out all HTML5 tags such as `<nav>` which I need for the site I am converting.

I have read about the issue here: http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/customising-the-cms/show/69101

And tried each of the solutions and flushed the cache with no results. This is not surprising as most of the people in the thread have the same result.

I also tried this module: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-html5

With the same results. No change.

Is it possible to enable HTML5 tags easily with a configuration option and without modifying the framework or CMS code? If so is there an example of this online?

All resources, comments, links and solutions are apreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3.1 calling [`setOption('extended_valid_elements', ...)`](http://doc.silverstripe.com/en/developer_guides/forms/field_types/htmleditorfield/#setting-options) in `mysite/_config.php` works for me:

```php
HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOption(
    'extended_valid_elements',
    'img[class|src|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name|usemap|data*],'
        . 'iframe[src|name|width|height|align|frameborder|marginwidth|marginheight|scrolling],'
        . 'object[width|height|data|type],'
        . 'embed[src|type|pluginspage|width|height|autoplay],'
        . 'param[name|value],'
        . 'map[class|name|id],'
        . 'area[shape|coords|href|target|alt],'
        . 'ol[start|type]'
        . 'address[class|name|id],'
        . 'article[class|name|id],'
        . 'aside[class|name|id],'
        . 'audio[class|name|id],'
        . 'bdi[class|name|id],'
        . 'caption[class|name|id],'
        . 'canvas[class|name|id],'
        . 'datalist[class|name|id],'
        . 'details[class|name|id],'
        . 'dialog[class|name|id],'
        . 'embed[class|name|id],'
        . 'figure[class|name|id],'
        . 'figcaption[class|name|id],'
        . 'footer[class|name|id],'
        . 'header[class|name|id],'
        . 'keygen[class|name|id],'
        . 'mark[class|name|id],'
        . 'menuitem[class|name|id],'
        . 'meter[class|name|id],'
        . 'nav[class|name|id],'
        . 'output[class|name|id],'
        . 'progress[class|name|id],'
        . 'rp[class|name|id],'
        . 'rt[class|name|id],'
        . 'ruby[class|name|id],'
        . 'section[class|name|id],'
        . 'source[class|name|id],'
        . 'summary[class|name|id],'
        . 'time[class|name|id],'
        . 'track[class|name|id],'
        . 'video[class|name|id],'
        . 'wbr[class|name|id]'
);
```

Comment: I have tried this, also I have tried replacing the ```valid_elements``` and it doesn't work for me.

Are you using version ( 3.1 )

Comment: Yes, I am using SilverStripe 3.1 . Try pasting the code above into your config. I noticed there was a slight difference between the code in the forums and what the code in framework uses. Mainly the code in framework doesn't have any white space between tags. Copying the framework way worked for me.

Comment: Sweet This worked. for some reason the ones similar that were posted in the threads didn't work.